# Native network-related functions randomly blocking in android

Tags: android, c, native

I have a library written in C that I'm using from an Android application. I discovered that the application blocks sometimes while executing various functions (what is common is they are all related to networking).

I'm testing on a real Android device running Android 6.
The library is compiled with NDK version 21.

So far I have observed this behavior with 3 functions - `getaddrinfo`, `poll` and `socket`:

```
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &result);

////

struct pollfd wait = {
    .fd = fd,
    .events = event,
    .revents = 0
};
status = poll(&wait, 1, 10000);

////

fd = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
```

These functions are called several times each after the program starts running. The same call can work fine one time and block indefinitely (at least several minutes) the next time. The internet connection on the device seems to be fine.

Any ideas? How can I even approach debugging such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't actually find the reason for the problem, but I found how to fix it. Part of the code was written by somebody else and I wasn't sure what exactly it was doing. After rewriting this part, everything started to work fine.

Among other things, the code was spawning a new process with `fork()`. I suspect the problem to be related to that.